# What happened to Jiří Menzel's documentary about Croatia?

Tags: documentary

I know that the legendary late Czech director Jiří Menzel was filming a documentary about Croatia some 10+ years ago. I don't see it in his filmography. Does anyone know what happened to that documentary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called "Vaše moře, naše moře" (Your Sea, Our Sea), can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYzNbDpGzHw). I did not find any English reference to this work though.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know if it was finsihed. I'm from Croatia BTW (regardless of the Czech name)